# Updating addresses in remote copy of table

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with more than 23,000 rows, and a partial copy of it (different number of columns) at a remote location. In the past month several hundred rows have been updated with address changes, and I need to replicate those updates to the remote copy. I have "adminer" available but it will not allow importing since the number of columns is not the same. I do not have full access to the database at the remote site, making it difficult if not impossible to use LOADFILE with the REPLACE option. What are my options in such a case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better solution will be, drop that table &  import Live table data to remote location.

If you don't want to import then, add new columns in remote table. Take dump from live table. Open it in any text editor. Choose insert query of new changes & run it mysql command line. It will insert data.

PS: To avoid it in future, start replication of Table. All new changes in live table will automatically be reflected in remote table.

Comment: Not long after posting the question, I realized that the simplest solution would be to drop the existing remote table and replace it with an abbreviated version of the local master, with all financial data stripped out. Part of the ptoblem is that my DBA prefers to maintain the master using MSAccess rather than MySQL! However he can create me a CSV file that I can import into the remote copy via phpMyAdmin. We tested that this morning and it works, in his words, great. Thanks to all who have contributed to my learning of the options, even though it turned out to be a non-problem after all.

Answer (score 0):

If we can make a connection to the remote MySQL server from our local box.

```
mysql -h remote_host ...
```

Then we could use a `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` statement to read a file from our local system, and `REPLACE` into the remote table.

We just need to extract the local table into a file in a format suitable for the LOAD DATA statement.

---

It's not at all clear what access is available. All we know is that you don't "have full access", and we don't know what that means.

Another approach would be to create a new copy of the table (into a different database on the remote MySQL server), with all of the columns.  Using mysqldump to extract the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements into a .sql file, and then  executing the .sql (from our local client) connected to the remote MySQL server.

If there's a PRIMARY KEY constraint or a UNIQUE index, we can use a SQL statements to refresh the less-columned table from the full table.

```
INSERT IGNORE ...
UPDATE target t JOIN source s ON ... SET t.foo = s.foo ...
```

Or

```
INSERT INTO target ( ... ) 
SELECT ... 
  FROM source 
ON DUPLICATE KEY
   UPDATE foo = VALUES(foo)
```

---